# Reference numeric identifier from postively predicted target

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I built a machine learning model that was able to accurately predict potentially fraudulent customers. My dataset is around 12,000 observations and around 43 features(and around 147 after I one hot encoded several features). Each row corresponds to a different customer, and I have a feature called `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` which contains each customer's numeric identifier(so since there are around 12,000 customers there are around 12,000 unique numeric identifiers). Since this feature is an identifier, I do not include it in the machine learning model itself and I drop it from my original dataframe(along with other features such as date,etc.)

```
 df = df.drop(['CUSTOMER_NUMBER','TRANSACT_DT','CUSTOMER_NAME'],axis=1)
```

After running my model

```
 #get this loss year: 
 #train loss year =2014-2016 
 #test loss year = 2017
 this_year = 'LY_' + str((pd.to_datetime('today').year)-1)


#partition train and test set by this LY
train = df.loc[df[this_year] == 0]
test = df.loc[df[this_year] == 1]



X_train =train.drop(['Target_Variable'],axis=1)
X_test =test.drop(['Target_Variable'],axis=1)
y_train = train['Target_Variable']
y_test = test['Target_Variable']
training_data = X_train,y_train
test_data = X_test,y_test


clf2= SVC(C=100,kernel='linear',class_weight='balanced')


#class_weight = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y_train), y_train)
clf2.fit(X_train, y_train)
X = df.drop(['Target_Variable'],axis=1)


#define the predicted estimators
y_pred = clf2.predict(X_test)
```

and evaluating my true positive rate, I was able to predict the some of rows where `df['Target_Variable'] ==1`. However, although I'm able to get a list the predicted 1's by `print(y_pred==1)` it does me no good if I do not know which customer number (which I dropped from my dataframe) it corresponds to. Thus I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to get the customer numbers that correspond to `y_pred==1`? Or should I not drop the feature `df['CUSTOMER_NUMBER']` and include it in my model? If so, would it alter my predictive results since it is just a unique numeric identifier?

Comment: It's better to don't drop columns and instead write a list of `features`.  you then can call  `clf2.fit(X_train[features], y_train)`.
Then I'd suggest to use `df[df[this_year] == 0]` instead of `df.loc[df[this_year] == 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first comment. You shouldnt include 'CUSTOMER_NUMBER' as feature. Since every number is unique, it doesnt add any value to your model. Just create a subset of features

```
clf2.fit(X_train[features], y_train)
```

and when you want to know the 'CUSTOMER_NUMBER'

```
df.loc[df['y_pred'] == 1, 'CUSTOMER_NUMBER']
```